# How to convert a list of values into comma separated string in Hugo template

Tags: html, go, hugo

I am new to Hugo, know nothing about GoLang and I am trying to do the following.

#### Problem

I have a Hugo site, and in my posts, I specify `keywords` in the front matter like:

```
---
author: Andrea Tino
keywords:
- language
- image
- fun
---
```

In my template, I want to add a `<meta>` for keywords, so I have:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ if .Keywords }}
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ .Keywords }}">
    {{ end }}
    <title>{{ .Title }} | {{ .Site.Title }}</title>
</head>
```

The problem, of course, is that I get this in the output:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="[language image fun]">
    <title>{{ .Title }} | {{ .Site.Title }}</title>
</head>
```

While my objective is to get:

```html
<meta name="keywords" content="language, image, fun">
```

How to achieve this?

---

#### What I have tried

Looking at this [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions), I have tried to play a little:

```html
{{ if .Keywords }}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ .Keywords | println }}">
{{ end }}
```

Also tried:

```html
{{ if .Keywords }}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ .Keywords | printf "%s" }}">
{{ end }}
```

They do not work. Also tried:

```html
{{ if .Keywords }}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ println(strings.Join(.Keywords, ", ")) }}">
{{ end }}
```

This last one causes an error:

> Error: "/Users/me/Git/myproj/themes/mytheme/layouts/partials/header.html:7:1": parse failed: template: partials/header.html:7: unexpected "(" in operand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try

```
<p>Keywords: {{ delimit .Keywords ", " }}</p>
```

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try. Can you please help me understand the syntax? What is Go? And where does Hugo start? I mean, this {{ xxx }}`` syntax I understand being Hugo. Is it safe to understand that whatever falls inside those brackets is actual Go?

Answer (score 2):

Only output the meta tag when keywords are in your front matter:

```
{{- with delimit .Keywords "," -}}
  <meta name="keywords" content="{{.}}">
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Gonna give this a try thanks. Can you explain the difference between `{{ xxx }}` and `{{- xxcx -}}`?

Comment: [Trimming](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#whitespace) the whitespace !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I selected @Sefa's is because it is a one liner :) But yours is valuable and allowed me to understand a few things. Thank you.